# How to put a dodecahedron inside another dodecahedron?

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I know how to put a sphere inside a dodecahedron but instead of a sphere I would like it to be another dodecahedron. How can I do it?

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.3], FaceForm[Yellow], 
   PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]}, Brown, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}],
   Boxed -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.3], FaceForm[Yellow], 
   Scale[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], #] & /@ 
    Range[.1, 1, .1]}}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kuba has identified the missing piece of the puzzle in his comment, `Scale`. With `Scale` you can make the dodecahedron smaller or larger. Other than that it's just a matter of replacing `Sphere`.

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.3], FaceForm[Yellow], 
   PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]}, Brown, 
  Scale[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], 0.5]},Boxed -> False]
```

[image: dodec]

Note where I placed `Boxed`. You include `Boxed -> False` but because its position is wrong it doesn't actually do anything in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I personally tend to avoid using things like `Scale[]` when applying transformations to primitives. Instead, I just apply `TransformationFunction[]` objects directly to primitives, one way or another. As an example,

```
dod = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"];
ir = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Inradius"];
sc = ScalingTransform[RootReduce[ir/PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Circumradius"]]
                      {1, 1, 1}];

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.4, Yellow], dod}, {Opacity[0.6, LightBlue], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, ir]},
            {Green, MapAt[sc, dod, 1]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: inscribed dodecahedron]

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0, 1]], {Opacity[0.3, Orange], dod},
            {Yellow, MapAt[sc, dod, 1]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: two dodecahedra]

Comment: @Christopher, sorry about that; should be fixed now.